# How to combine multiple assert_that in Hamcrest?

Tags: python, hamcrest

I'm using PyHamcrest but I think this question is language agnostic.

I would like to turn:

```
assert_that(actual0, matcher0)
assert_that(actual1, matcher1)
```

into a single assert so that if both assertions fail, the error message says so. Can this be done in Hamcrest (or some other package/module)?

In Python, I've implemented:

```
def assert_all(*assertions):
    assertion_failed = False
    assertion_message = []

    for (actual, matcher) in assertions:
        try:
            hamcrest.assert_that(actual, matcher)
        except AssertionError as e:
            assertion_failed = True

            assertion_message.append(e.message)

    if assertion_failed:
        raise AssertionError(''.join(assertion_message))
```

so my test would call:

```
assert_all(
    (actual0, matcher0),
    (actual1, matcher1))
```

but I'm wondering if there's already an implementation of something like this.

Comment: I also wish there was a tool for Python that combined Hamcrest matchers and the idea of soft (delayed) asserts. https://github.com/pr4bh4sh/delayed-assert is good for soft (delayed) asserts and https://github.com/hamcrest/PyHamcrest is good for Hamcrest matching in assertions. But I haven't seen anything that mixes the two concepts together, unfortunately. A coworker and I wrote something like this (a `SoftHamcrestAssert` class) for Java at my previous job, and I may have to roll my own for Python at my current job.

Answer (score 1):

Pass a sequence of values (list or tuple) for the `actual` value and the same number of matchers as parameters to [`contains`](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/source/browse/trunk/hamcrest-python/hamcrest/library/collection/issequence_containinginorder.py):

```
assert_that((actual0, actual1, ...), contains(matcher0, matcher1, ...))
```

The list of matchers is applied in order to the sequence of actual values, one-by-one. All must match for the assertion to pass.

Comment: If both assertions fail, only the first one is reported.

Comment: Normally the actual values would be returned by a method already as a sequence. I don't see why you'd want to combine assertions on two separate values like in your example, but perhaps a concrete example would illustrate better. Keep in mind that the Hamcrest matchers are used for more than assertions such as for mocking methods.

Comment: Can you please open a ticket on the project?

Comment: My script selectively 'copies' files from a main development branch to a release branch. The assertions check to ensure that those files that are supposed to be copied are copied and those that aren't supposed to be copied aren't.

Ideally there's only one object that's verified, but I don't see that can be done for my script.

Comment: Should tickets be filed at https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=66150&atid=513503?

Comment: We're in the process of moving Hamcrest to Github, e.g. [PyHamcrest](https://github.com/hamcrest/PyHamcrest). The issue tracker isn't enabled and I don't know if we're moving that from GoogleCode (probably). For now file a ticket [here](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/issues/list), and I'll copy it over if it turns out we're moving those too.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/issues/detail?id=183&thanks=183&ts=1337016145. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hamcrest assertions are intended to be matchers for a single object, so what you're asking is difficult to fit into the model elegantly. In general, I think any solution you kludge together is going to look at least as bad as separate assertions. For my part, I prefer separate assertions for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it will be to late, but

## assertions.py

```
class AssertAllContext(AbstractContextManager):
    def __init__(self):
        self.errors: List[str] = []

    def assert_that(self, actual, matcher, message: Optional[str] = None):
        try:
            assert_that(actual, matcher, reason=message)
        except AssertionError as e:
            self.errors.append(str(e))

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        if self.errors:
            out = 'assertion failures:'
            for i, msg in enumerate(self.errors):
                out += f'\n{i + 1}. {msg}'
            self.errors = []
            raise AssertionError(out)
```

## test_a.py

```
    def test_a(self):
        with AssertAllContext() as a_all:
            a_all.assert_that(2 + 1, is_(4), message="Error 1")
            a_all.assert_that("hello world", is_("hello"), message="Error 2")
            a_all.assert_that(4.14159, is_(3.14), message="Error 3")
```